# Create a SVN Repository from the client.

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Lets say that I just started a new Project, and want to create a repository for it, being just a client, not the actual admin of the SVN server. How do i do it?

I can create a repository at the server itself, but I can't create one repository from the client, for example Tortoise, I can create branches, tags etc, but no repository.

obs: the create repository of tortoise creates it locally, not at actual svn server. 
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Are you attempting to create a repository through tortoisesvn on an svn server that you do not have administrative rights to?

Comment: I do have administrative rights, i just want another users to have this capabilities.

Answer (score 4):

According to [a post in the SVN mailing list](http://svn.haxx.se/tsvnusers/archive-2007-02/0005.shtml) (and common knowledge among SVN users), it's not possible to create a repository remotely *using a SVN client*. What you *can* do, for example, is write a web application that creates repositories on the server if you are so inclined. But if the server isn't in your control, you're out of luck.

Comment: the server is under my control, just want another users to have the capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use something like [Subversion Edge](http://www.open.collab.net/products/subversion/SVNedge.html) for your server you get a web UI for configuring and managing the server, which allows you to create repositories from your web browser.  Also, Subversion Edge has a [REST API](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/2012/03/subversion-server-automation/) that lets you work with the server programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

So, this may not be the solution you are looking for, but I had a similar situation (I had some interns that didn't have admin privs on the server, but I didn't want to have to create new repos for them every time they created a new project and wanted to check it in. Similarly, I didn't want to have to fire up CollabNet to make a new repo every time I wanted to check in some brand new simple test project.)

I created a personalized "root" repository on the server (e.g. "InternNameProjects") *without* the standard Trunk/Branches/Tabs structure, and gave the url to the intern. He can now use TSVN to `Browse Repo` at that url, and create a new folder there. Then use the [Import In Place](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-import.html#tsvn-dug-import-in-place) instructions to place the new project into that folder (two steps: 1. check out over the top, 2. commit).

Answer (score 0):

A Subversion client can only operate on existing repositories, so no. You cannot *create* a repository with a Subversion client. There are a few things you can do:

- You can write a web app that will allow users to create a Subversion repository. Writing such an app using JavaScript or PHP isn't that difficult. If you define Apache `httpd` to specify `SVNParentPath`, adding a  new repository to the directory specified by `SVNParentPath` would make that Subversion repository accessible via Apache `httpd`. You don't even have to restart Apache.
- You can redefine your way out of the situation by saying instead of *repository* just *project*. That is, instead of multiple repositories with one project per repository, have one repository with multiple projects. Then, someone could use `svn mkdir $REPO/trunk/$project` to create a new project from their Subversion client. They will have their new project and can treat it just like a separate Subversion repository.